# 404 error when updating system on ubuntu 21.10 (impish)

Tags: 21.10

so I tried to update ubuntu 21.10 on raspberry pi using terminal and it says this error:

```
Err:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
```

please help me fix this

edit: I already tried changing the sources to port but it keeps on showing this error

here is the whole terminal text if it helps:

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish InRelease
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe Sources [17.1 MB]
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main Sources [1,320 kB]
Get:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted Sources [18.3 kB]
Get:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse Sources [290 kB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Ign:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main ppc64el Packages
Ign:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main armhf Packages
Ign:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main s390x Packages
Ign:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe ppc64el Packages
Ign:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe s390x Packages
Ign:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main ppc64el Packages
Ign:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main armhf Packages
Ign:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main s390x Packages
Ign:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe ppc64el Packages
Ign:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe s390x Packages
Ign:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main ppc64el Packages
Ign:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main armhf Packages
Ign:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main s390x Packages
Ign:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe ppc64el Packages
Ign:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe s390x Packages
Ign:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main ppc64el Packages
Ign:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main armhf Packages
Ign:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main s390x Packages
Ign:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe ppc64el Packages
Ign:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe s390x Packages
Ign:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main ppc64el Packages
Ign:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main armhf Packages
Ign:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main s390x Packages
Ign:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe ppc64el Packages
Ign:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe s390x Packages
Err:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:30 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main ppc64el Packages
Ign:34 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main armhf Packages
Ign:35 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main s390x Packages
Ign:36 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe ppc64el Packages
Ign:38 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe s390x Packages
Fetched 270 kB in 8s (32.2 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_CA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_CA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/impish/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_CA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_CA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ca_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-impish.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ports_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-ports_-impish.list:3
```

Comment: arm64 is a port, and doesn't use the main archive.   ie. http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/  (needed for arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x etc)

Comment: The following worked for me This is my last line: `deb-src [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main universe restricted multiverse`. What I think this is doing is traversing packages for amd64, but ultimately ignoring arch specific ones. If it's not source it's not going to work... so I only included source. Finally, being last means ports packages take priority.